# Rotating array anti-clockwise, unexpected debug output in one step

Tags: c, arrays, debugging, data-structures

I'm using the simplest approach to rotate array anti-clockwise i.e by storing elements from index=0 to index=number of rotating positions required, in a temporary array and finally inserting these elements int he end of another array. Here's the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int *a, *temp, i, j=0, n,np,*b;
    printf("Enter no. of elements in arr:\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    a=(int*) malloc(n*sizeof(int));//Primary array
    b=(int*) malloc(n*sizeof(int));//Final array that would be printed in the end
    printf("Enter elements:\n");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    printf("Enter positions to be rotated anti-clockwise:\n");
    scanf("%d",&np);
    temp=(int*) malloc(np*sizeof(int));//storing elements left of index=0
    for(i=0;i<np;i++,j++)
    {
        //printf("hi\n");
        temp[j]=a[i];
        printf("temp[%d]=%d\n",j,temp[j]);
    }
    j=0;
    printf("After rotating:\n");
    for(i=n-1;i>=0;i--)
    {
        printf("i=%d ",i);
        b[i-np]=a[i];
        printf("b[%d]=%d\n",i-np,b[i]); /*Here is 1 unexpected thing happening, the program is not picking up correct value of array a at index i.*/
    }
    for(i=np-1;i<n;i++,j++)
        b[i]=temp[j];//storing temp elements in final array

    printf("Finally matrix is\n");

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        printf("%d\n",b[i]);

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean with the word anti-clockwise?  Are you trying to put your array elements somewhat in a circle manner?  Please, explain.

Answer (score 1):

Either you try to rotate the array elements one direction or the other, the procedure is always the same: Take a copy of the extremum element you ar going to move to the other extreme.  Then, copy the next element (from the element you saved to the other side) into the hole you have opened.  Finally, cover the hole with the saved element.

```
typedef int ARRAY_ELEMENT;
ARRAY_ELEMENT the_array[N_ELEMENTS];

/* to put the first element at the end */
ARRAY_ELEMENT saved_element = the_array[0];
for (int i = 1; i < N_ELEMENTS; i++) the_array[i-1] = the_array[i];
the_array[N_ELEMENTS-1] = saved_element;

/* to put the last element at the beginning */
ARRAY_ELEMENT saved_element = the_array[N_ELEMENTS-1];
for (int i = N_ELEMENTS-1; i > 0; i--) the_array[i] = the_array[i-1];
the_array[0] = saved_element;
```

You can do this also by swapping the first element with the second, the second to the third, etc... up to the next to last and the last.  You'll reach the same result, but with a lot of more assignments (three assignments per round, instead of one)

if you want only to rotate part of an array, design a routine that considers the pointer to the first element and the number of these as parameters... and then apply it to the array part you want to rotate.

```
void rotate_upwards(ARRAY_ELEMENT *a, size_t n) /* a[0] -> a[1], a[1] -> a[2] ... */
{
    ARRAY_ELEMENT saved = a[n-1];
    int i;
    for (i = n-1; i > 0; i--) a[i] = a[i-1];
    a[i] = saved;
} /* rotate_upwards */

void rotate_downwards(ARRAY_ELEMENT *a, size_t n) /* a[0] <- a[1], ... */
{
    ARRAY_ELEMENT saved = a[0];
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++) a[i] = a[i+1];
    a[i] = saved;
} /* rotate_downwards */
```

if you want then to rotate `5` elements of `array[100]` at position `33`, you can use

```
rotate_downwards(array + 33, 5);
```

and you'll rotate only a slice of an array.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly in the incriminated print you are printing the rotated array. 
The problem is with the element you are printing:

```
printf("b[%d]=%d\n",i-np,b[i]);
```

You in fact are printing `b[i]`, I think that there you want to print either `a[i]` or `b[i-np]`.

Comment: Yeah I corrected it, but still getting garbage value i  the final array.

Answer (score 0):

This loop where you remark "unexpected thing" is in error

```
for(i=n-1;i>=0;i--)
{
    printf("i=%d ",i);
    b[i-np]=a[i];               // <--- error here
    printf("b[%d]=%d\n",i-np,b[i]); /*Here is 1 unexpected thing happening, the program is not picking up correct value of array a at index i.*/
}
```

You are indexing `b[i-np]` which will break `b` when `i < np`, which it will be.

I can't suggest a solution, since I don't understand what the question means by "rotating an array anti-clockwise".

Comment: Suppose a={1,2,3,4} and we have to rotate it in anti-clockwise manner by one position then final array will be: {2,3,4,1}

Comment: @sahildhawan please give an example involving `np`. Post the input array, the value of `np` and the expected output array in your question, not in comment.